Clicking a link in an email does not open said link in any browser
Using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS; Gnome version 3.36.8 along with Thunderbird Mail version 128.5.1esr (64-bit) and Firefox version 133.0 (64-bit) - though what browser I set as default does not change the problem. Something happened quite a while ago and clicking a link in an email does not open said link in any browser. I am hoping for something that I can do in Terminal (some code) that will restore the functionality. Thanks.

Configure the mail client Firefox uses
Click the menu button and select Settings.
Select the General panel and go to the Applications section.
Under content type, find mailto and select it.
In the row for "mailto," click the Action column to change the action.
Always Ask will ask you about the program you want to use whenever you use an email feature.
Using  (default) will automatically open the new message window of your operating system's email program (e.g., Thunderbird, Evolution, KMail).
Using  will open the new message page of your webmail service (Gmail) within Firefox.
Use Other... allows you to specify an external program for Firefox to run.
Application Details... allows you to view information about the application or remove webmail services that Firefox can use.
--------Edited--------
Try the following:
Open the location of your Thunderbird profile file.
~/.thunderbird/<profile name>

Find handlers.json.
Edit it with a text editor.
Look for schemes and under it modify it to something like:
"schemes":{
"https":{
"action":2,
"handlers":[
{
"name":"Librewolf",
"command":"librewolf %u"
},
{
"name":"Firefox Web Browser",
"command":"firefox %u"
},
{
"name":"brave-browser-stable",
"path":"/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable"
}
],
"ask":true
}

Under handlers provide at least 2 options (They do not need to be installed) or the 'Always ask' option will not work.
Save the file and reopen Thunderbird
Browse to an email with a link
Click the link and a dialog box should open allowing you to choose the browser.
If you choose 'Always use this app to open https links', the dialog box should disappear in the future and the selected one should always start as default.
------End-----
--------Edited-----
Thunderbird and Firefox are Mozilla products. By default, Thunderbird should open links in emails with Firefox and Firefox should open email addresses with Thunderbird.
To try to restore this setting, who knows why it was lost on your system:
Start Thunderbird.
Look for: Edit ---> Preferences.
Once there, in the window that opens, look for:
Advanced ---> General.
Once in this item, you need to click on: Configuration Editor.
A warning window should appear, in which you should click: I accept the risk!
Next in Search, you need to search for: network.protocol-handler.warn-external
Under network.protocol-handler.warn-external-default, the last three entries should appear as false.
These are:
network.protocol-handler.warn-external-ftp
network.protocol-handler.warn-external-http
network.protocol-handler.warn-external-https

By double clicking on each of them you must change them to true
Close the window.
Theoretically, the next time you open a link from Thunderbird it should ask you which program to open the links with.

It's already set as you suggest in Firefox. BUT, I think you might have misunderstood my question. When I click a mailto link in Firefox, it opens a new email in Thunderbird Mail (the correct and default mail handler) as it should. So that's not the problem. The problem is the opposite: When I click a link in a (Thunderbird Mail) email, it should open it in Firefox but it doesn't; it doesn't do anything at all. Even if I set a different browser as default, clicking a link in (an email) in Thunderbird Mail does nothing. The problem is in Thunderbird apparently. Tried reinstalling but no help.

Post are edited.

Tried editing handlers.json as you suggested but that didn't help. Still can't open emailed links in any browser. I have to copy and paste them.

@Jody B: New edition.

I have tried everything that has been suggested so far and links clicked in Thunderbird still do nothing at all. I've even tried renaming handlers.json to something else, letting TB create new ones but still no help.

Final post on this. I uninstalled Thunderbird. Then I installed it from flathub and this one works. I never did get the other installation working.

Final post on this. I uninstalled Thunderbird. Then I installed it from flathub and this one works. I never did get the other installation working.
